# LibGDX - How do I add a background Image

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've just started learning LibGDX and I'm taking it very slowly. I've looked at numerous tutorials for how to add a background images to a game but most of them are outdated or too difficult for a beginner like me. Below is what I have tried to get the image to display.

```
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.jpg"));
    backgroundTexture = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 2048, 563)
```

Unfortunately, It didn't work. I ran the application and the screen was still black and plain.

Like I said, I'm new at this so please make you explanation as simple as possible.

Comment: Please include more details about how it didn't work.  Does it not compile?  Can you run the app?  Do you see anything on screen?  Do you get an exception message in the log?  (Please include the exception message if you get one.)

Comment: I ran the application and the screen was still black as always and their was nothing their.

Comment: you need to draw the texture region using the `SpriteBatch` in the `render()` function. I recommend looking at the initial code that LibGDX generates for you when you first create the project - it displays an image.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a texture but then you never use it. Visit [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch%2C-Textureregions%2C-and-Sprites) to get more information on how to actually draw things on the screen. If that is to confusing I suggest finding tutorials on java before going any further with the library

Answer (score 0):

ou only assigned your `texture` field a image and then put that in a `TextureRegion` field. You are not actually drawing with this since this happens within the `SpriteBatch.Begin()` and `SpriteBatch.End()`.

In your constructor or `create` method you should have what you did:

```
public void create() {
    //...
    backgroundTexture = new TextureRegion(new Texture("background.jpg"), 0, 0, 2048, 563);
    //Those are weird screen sizes btw (2048/563)
    //...
}
```

In your `render` method you should have this:

```
public void render() {
    //...
    batch.Begin();
    batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 0, 0);
    //I believe texture region takes the upper left corner as 0,0 and batch.Draw the bottom left.
    //So you might need to do something like this:
    batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    batch.End();
    //...
}
```

This should at least draw it for you. If you have a camera that is not pointing at the right coordinates then obviously you won't see it or just part of it. But if you did not fiddle with the `batch.setProjectionMatrix` you should be good.

*Disclamer:* I just wrote stuff out here with a bit of help from the documentation so it might not work immediately.

Comment: Is there a way to always preserve the aspect ratio when resizing textures/backgrounds?

Answer (score 0):

draw it on the render method

spritebatch.begin();

spritebatch.draw(texture, 0,0, width_of _screen, height_of_screen);

spritebatch.end();

Answer (score 0):

```
package <<here your package name>>;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;


public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;
    @Override
    public void create() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    img = new Texture("background.png");//name of your file.type
    
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,0,0,1);//the color of the backgrond if your image small than the windows
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();

    
        batch.draw(img,0,0,1000,700);// image,x,y,wight,height

//this one  for getting your image in center if it was icon or small image
        //batch.draw(img,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - img.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 - img.getHeight()/2);
        //batch.draw(batch,text,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add text outside of your code snippet to explain what this code does?

Comment: this code is taking an image as background to your libgdx game using bach.draw with parameters needed or you want

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make it simple:
What you did is you created a texture called "texture" from the background.png
Now that just means that you load the texture in memory. But you want to draw it on the screen. So in your show() method create a Spritebatch. A Spritebatch is a tool that helps you draw things on screen.

```
private SpriteBatch batch;

@Override
public void show () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
}
```

Then you have to draw the background onto the screen with the SpriteBatch.

```
 @Override
public void render(float delta) {
    batch.draw(texture, 0, 0, 200, 200);
}          //  texture, X, Y, width, height
```

Now this will draw you the texture on screen. But it wont fill your screen. To fill your entire screen we have to make it as big as the screen is.
You can get the screen height with

```
Gdx.graphics.getHeight()
```

and the width with

```
Gdx.graphics.getWidth()
```

Answer (score -5):

To make it repeating use a for statement, for my background which has a length of 700 and a width of 500 and I have a game 10 screens big (19200 x 10800 pixels),

```
for(int PositionX = 0; PositionX < 19200; PositionX += 700) {
    for(int PositionY = 0; PositionY < 10800; PositionY += 500) {
        SpriteBatch.draw(Background, PositionX, PositionY);
    }
}
```